# jpackage error- configured main jar does not exist

Tags: java, jar, jlink, jpackage

I am trying to package my app using jpackage. I'm sure my commands are correct, but it keeps giving me an error, saying that my main jar doesn't exist.

I used jdeps to find the dependencies of my app, and then, I used jlink to create a reduced jre for the app. I checked, and the created jre runs my app. Then, I proceeded to use jpackage to package my app. For this, I wrote the following in the Command Prompt:

`C:\Users\user1>jpackage --input \Desktop\Apps --name MathbeeApp --main-jar Mathbee1.jar --main-class main.MainThread --type exe`

I also tried to change the type:

`C:\Users\user1>jpackage --input \Desktop\Apps --name MathbeeApp --main-jar Mathbee1.jar --main-class main.MainThread --type app-image`

But I always get the same errors:

> Bundler EXE Installer Package skipped because of a configuration problem: the configured main jar does not exist Mathbee1.jar in the input directory
> Advice to fix: the main jar must be specified relative to the input directory (not an absolute path), and must exist within that directory

and

> Bundler EXE Installer Package skipped because of a configuration problem: the configured main jar does not exist Mathbee1.jar in the input directory
> Advice to fix: the main jar must be specified relative to the input directory (not an absolute path), and must exist within that directory

respectively.

But I made sure that my jar file is in the directory. I attached a picture of my directory. I don't understand why it says that it doesn't exist. Can somebody help me with this problem?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SiX1C.png)

Comment: I don't know if this is causing the problem, but what if you try `--input .\Desktop\Apps` (with the `.` at the front; it may be that the leading ``\`` by itself makes Java interpret as an absolute path, though I would expect it to complain the directory does not exist in that case)? You might also want to make sure you aren't mixing up OneDrive's "desktop" with the local computer's desktop. And be careful with using `Desktop\Apps` as the input directory. You have `diet-jre` in there, which I assume is the `jlink`-ed image; I doubt you want to "include" that in the final package.

Comment: As an aside, I recommend you use `--runtime-image` given you're building a custom run-time image ahead-of-time. Otherwise, `jpackage` will run `jlink` itself.

Comment: Double check you have shown us the commands exactly as you typed, as there is a space in `-- main-jar` which would be an error.

Comment: @Slaw, thanks for your input. It worked. I was working from a tablet with my microsoft username and the Desktop gets synced into OneDrive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comments to my question, I was able to figure out that the solution was to make sure the input directory is not in OneDrive. Once I made sure of this, jpackage was able to find the main jar.